# cache issue on loading CSS in a LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html

I have a CSS issue that I am not sure how to solve.
I created on table that loop over to set of data one after the other.
In order to differentiate between the 2 sources I added a dark grey background.

The table and the two data sources are updated based on the Region selected.
my issue is that if I change region my css is not updated have a look at the video
The row 'total' should always be dark grey.. while the other default (for that I use the class total-color that refers to the css property)

[image]

it seems that the CSS is kept in the cache.
Any idea ??

HTML code:

```
<template>
    <article class="slds-card">
    <lightning-card title="DAS Progress table">
           
              
        <div class="slds-scrollable_x slds-var-m-left_x-small" style="height:100%">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table--edit slds-table--bordered slds-table_cell-buffer column-bordered-table" style="table-layout:fixed;" >
                <thead>
                    <tr class="">
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="whitespace" title="Market">Region</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="whitespace" title="Name">Country</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="whitespace" title="Stage">Total markets</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="whitespace" title="Deal type">Markets qualified</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="whitespace" title="Signing Date">Market to qualify</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="whitespace" title="Opening Date">Property supply</div>
                        </th> 
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="whitespace" title="Property # Keys">Total Qualified properties</div>
                        </th>
                        
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="whitespace" title="Bed Spaces">Properties contacted</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="whitespace" title="Number of Keys">Qualified, not contacted</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="whitespace" title="Asking Price">Qualified, not willing to trade</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="whitespace" title="Asking Price">Qualified, willing to trade</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="whitespace" title="Offer Price">Qualified, willing to trade(DAS)</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="whitespace" title="Technical fees">Total Opportunities</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="whitespace" title="Total investment">Early stage</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="" title="Price per Key">Advanced Negociation</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="" title="Rent/Key/Month">Closing</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="" title="UW link">Closed Won</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="columnsize slds-var-p-around_large" scope="col">
                            <div class="" title="UW link">Abandoned</div>
                        </th>
                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
                <template if:true={tableData}>
                <template for:each = {tableData} for:item = "item" for:index="indexVar">
                    <tr key={item.key} class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.RegionName}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.CountryName}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.MarketSupply}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.MarketsQualified}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.MarketsNotQualified}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.PropertySupplyInMarket}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.PropertiesQualifiedInMarket}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.PropertiesContactedInMarket}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.PropertiesQualifiedNotContactedInMarket}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.PropertiesContactedNotWillingInMarket}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.PropertiesContactedWillingInMarket}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.PropertiesDASContactedWillingInMarket}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.OppSupplyInMarket}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.OppEarlyStageInMarket}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.OppAdvancedNegoInMarket}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.OppClosingInMarket}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.OppClosedWonInMarket}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item.OppAbandonnedInMarket}
                            </div>
                        </td> 
                    </tr>
                </template>
                
                <template for:each = {tableTotal} for:item = "item2" for:index="indexVar">
                    <tr key={item2.key} class="slds-hint-parent total-color">
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    Total
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    Total
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalMarkets}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalMarketsQualified}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalMarketsToQualify}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalPropertySupply}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalQualifiedProperty}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalPropertiesContacted}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalQualifiedNotContacted}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalQualifiedNotWillingToTrade}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalQualifiedWillingToTrade}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalDASQualifiedWillingToTrade}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalOpportunities}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalEarlyStageOpportunities}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalAdvancedOpportunities}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalClosingOpportunities}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalClosedWonOpportunities}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="columnsize" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  class="lineReturn" title="Prospecting">  
                                    {item2.totalAbandonedOpportunities}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </template>
            <template if:false={tableData} class="slds-is-relative">
                <div style="height:100px">
                    <lightning-spinner
                    alternative-text="Loading..." variant="brand">
                </lightning-spinner>
                </div>
                
            </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
    </div>

    </lightning-card>
</article>

</template>
```

Comment: why for the last total line you are using iteration?

Comment: Because it is not the same data set .. it is a list of 1 element

Comment: then you don't need to use iteration if it is just one element. in js make from it plain object and use that. it could solve your issue with rendering.

Comment: Right I do not need the iteration but it did not solve my rendering issue ;)